# R - Plot time series as a heat map

Tags: r

I have a data set looking like this:

```
begin                    end                      id
2013-12-05 09:39:19.07   2013-12-05 14:29:00.47   1234
2013-12-06 07:34:23.55   2013-12-08 08:23:04.34   5678
```

It tracks the usage of a series of items.

I'd like to draw a heat map to see the usage of these items on a weekly basis.

I have thought of dividing each use into chunks of one hour to get a list of timestamps and plot the results using the methods described here:

[R: Plot timeseries as heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168963/r-plot-timeseries-as-heatmap)

Is there any R package/functions designed for this specific purpose or any better solution than what I am thinking of right now?

Comment: So what's wrong with the answer to the question you linked to?

Comment: It plots a timestamps. What I am looking for is a way to plot a timespan defined by the start/end date